# How to prevent csv injection in django application

Tags: python, django, file-upload, clamav, csv-injection

I am having a Django application with file upload feature. I am using Clamav to scan the file for viruses. I want to prevent CSV injection in my application too. I found this [stackoverflow](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/205216/can-clamav-detect-csv-injection) link related to it, but is of no help. Please suggest how to prevent CSV injection in my Django application with ClamAV.

Comment: perhaps you ask for a python solution built into the django application, then this question is more focused?

Comment: Alternatively ask in a separate question, whether ClamAV can detect CSV files with potential CSV injection cells. (independently of django)

I personally could only help with a python solution, but ClamAV specialists might jump in. However this question is probably better asked on https://superuser.com/

Comment: concerning your most recent edit:

You wrote: Please suggest how to achieve CSV injection in my Django application with ClamAV.

You probably mean:
 Please suggest how to achieve detection of CSV injection in my Django application with ClamAV.

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 2):

Look at the definition of CSV Injection (this link can be found in your SO link)
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSV_Injection

in short:

> When a spreadsheet program such as Microsoft Excel or LibreOffice Calc
>   is used to open a CSV, any cells starting with '=' will be interpreted
>   by the software as a formula. Maliciously crafted formulas can be used
>   for three key attacks:

You can prevent this attack by:

> This attack is difficult to mitigate, and explicitly disallowed from
>   quite a few bug bounty programs. To remediate it, ensure that no cells
>   begin with any of the following characters:
>
> ```
> Equals to ("=")
> Plus ("+")
> Minus ("-")
> At ("@")
> ```

I don't know how to do this with ClamAV as I don't use it, 
but you could write a small python function reading the file and ensuring that no cell starts with any of above characters.